# I locked myself out of my Gmail account and can't for the likes of me remember my password is there a way to display my credentials in plain English

Tags: client, credentials

I'm trying to display my credentials in plain english on html code using devtools I recently lost my mother and the only pictures I have of her are in my old google photos account but I can't remember my password and no longer have the same phone number, can someone please help ?

I've tried entering thr last password remembered but it wasn't enough for Google to verify even though it was the correct password before this one